# Service.restart() generates an huge unwanted amount of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, java.util.concurrent

When the user types in a TextField: I need to search some data via WebRequest and display them.

When the user types in more than one character, the previous download should be cancelled and a new one should start.

So I use a Task to download data and a Service to display data when the task returns them.

```
s = new Service(){
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task<String>(){
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                //DOWNLOAD DATA
                System.out.println("1");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("2");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("3");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return "banana";
            }
        };
    }
};
s.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getSource().getValue() + " DISPLAYED");
    }
});

//HANDLE KEY RELEASED ON A TEXTFIELD
public void onTextFieldKeyReleased() {
    s.restart();
}
```

I noticed that everytime Service is restarted another Thread appears, until a certain numbers of threads. 
This makes the program displaying data with a huge delay.

What I'd like the Service to do when the KeyReleasedEvent occurs is to cancel the Task that is currently running and starting a new one... not appending each time a new task.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the "huge delay" with the code you have posted. Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: @James_D Maybe you cannot reproduce the delay but you can see that a lot of threads are created, I don't want this to happen as well.
Also, I noticed that before printing every thread the service generated has to be closed, this takes a second and it's too much for me.

Comment: I don't see why creating a new thread would cause a problem, but did you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#setExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-)? What do you mean by "before printing every thread the service generated has to be closed"? I don't understand that. Can you at least edit your question with code that demonstrates that, even if you won't post code that demonstrates the delay?

Comment: @James_D "Calling Thread.sleep() isn't costly, but creating a thread might be." this is why I used service.
Anyway... I resolved the situation, at least for now, with ScheduledExecutorService initialized with newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor.
Instead of creating a lot of threads, this executor runs just a thread at once/

Comment: I would assume the default executor for service caches threads and runs new tasks on existing (unused) threads when possible (i.e. by default it probably uses a cached thread pool executor). What is your actual evidence it is creating so many threads anyway?

Comment: @James_D NetBeans lists current app threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the delay you mention.

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#setExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), `Service` uses "some default executor" to execute the `Task`s created by the `createTask` method. You can configure the executor if you want to modify the default behavior, for example:

```
s.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ;
});
```

Obviously you can use any executor you choose, depending on your exact requirements (which are not at all clear in your question). For example, if you wanted to limit to (say) 5 threads, you could do

```
s.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ;
});
```

Here's an SSCCE. I added some logging to track the status of the service and show the thread being used for the task:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ServiceRestartTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Service<Void> s = new Service<Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>(){
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        //DOWNLOAD DATA
                        System.out.println("New task on thread "+Thread.currentThread());
                        System.out.println("1");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("2");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("3");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        s.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }));

        s.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> System.out.println(newState));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(e -> s.restart());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(textField), 350, 120));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output, showing just two threads being used:

```
SCHEDULED
New task on thread Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
1
RUNNING
CANCELLED
READY
SCHEDULED
New task on thread Thread[Thread-6,5,main]
1
RUNNING
CANCELLED
READY
SCHEDULED
New task on thread Thread[Thread-6,5,main]
1
RUNNING
CANCELLED
READY
SCHEDULED
New task on thread Thread[Thread-6,5,main]
1
RUNNING
CANCELLED
READY
SCHEDULED
New task on thread Thread[Thread-6,5,main]
1
RUNNING
CANCELLED
READY
SCHEDULED
New task on thread Thread[Thread-6,5,main]
1
RUNNING
2
3
SUCCEEDED
```

Comment: It seems that setting the executor to Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() solves the too many threads issue

Comment: I tried your version but it doesn't work in my case, thank you anyway for helping me doing things the right way. If you edit your answer I will vote it.

Comment: You presumably don't need a scheduled executor (there is at least nothing at all in your question about scheduling). A single thread executor will cause problems if you really need two things to happen asynchronously. The cached thread pool reuses threads: I only see two threads being created here.